# How to write NULL IN SSIS expressions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2019, ssis-2019

Requirement:
Fullname = if type is "Y" then Name else NULL

I tried expression

```
 type == "y" ? Name : "NULL"
```

The field came as NULL as a string but would need as IS NULL

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you try `type == "y" ? Name : NULL(DT_STR,30,1252)`?

Comment: I tried this one, it didnt work